# Dynamically add form elements using jQquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been experimenting with the following code and seem to have everything worked out except forcing the cloned fields to stay open after the form fails validation. For example, if one or more of the cloned fields are open, someone fails to fill in a required field and submits the form, the opened cloned fields disappear after the form refreshes.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can force the open cloned fields to stay open when the form is submitted or refreshed?

Thanks,
Rob

```
<script> 
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
            newElem = $('#group' + num).clone().attr('id', 'group' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element

        //newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);

            newElem.find('.prod_num').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_product_name');
            newElem.find('.input_prod_num').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_product_name').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_product_name').val('');

            newElem.find('.serial_num').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_Serial_number');
            newElem.find('.input_serial_num').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_Serial_number').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_Serial_number').val('');

            newElem.find('.purch_date').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_purchase_Date').attr('class', 'purch_date');
//          newElem.find('.input_purch_date').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_purchase_Date').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_purchase_Date').val('');
            newElem.find('.input_purch_date').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_purchase_Date').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_purchase_Date').attr('class', 'purch_date').val('');
 $('.purch_date').datepicker('destroy');
    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#group' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_product_name').focus();

        var i = 0;
$('.purch_date').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("id",'date' + i).datepicker();
    i++;
});

        $('.purch_date').datepicker();


    // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // Change '5' below to the max number of times the form can be duplicated
        if (newNum == 9)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // confirmation
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this product? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#group' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false;
             // remove the last element

    // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: For future reference code snippets are for runnable code so that we can easily run the example. If the chunk of code you are displaying isn't a fully runnable snippet it should just be indented 4 spaces and it will look like formatted code without the snippet block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about a form submission problem but we don't see anything related to the submission of the form in your code. But i can tell you this. If the form is submit with a regular postback, it's normal that you lost everything you added dynamically. I would suggest you to submit the form with an ajax call or validate the form on your own before submiting the form like so :

```
$("myform").submit(function () {
    if(!$(this).validate())
    {
        //if the form don't validate, don't submit it
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you have validation on the server side. Make an ajax call to validate does thing.

```
$("myform").submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            //do what's appropriate
        }


    return false; //we control the behavior of the submission
});
```

Good luck